# Scheduled turn off & on on android 8.1

Tags: automation, 8.1-oreo

Scheduled turning the device off and on has apparently been discontinued in Android 8. 
Edit: At least for my device thats the case.

Given that it was one of my favorite functionalities in android 7, I would like to retain it through the update to 8.1.

Is there a similar function on 8.1 or an app i can use to emulate it?

Taskr and Automateit require root access to be able to shut down the device.

Comment: Search for "scheduled power on/off" in the settings. It should be there